# fancybox / jquery redirect on close

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox inline form here

http://keith464.fahrradhamburg.de/Messen/

- Anmelden

Point 1 - it "breaks" / i get the following error when i try to send the form

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' 
- which is for this line
`$("#send").on("click", function(){`

Ignoring that error, and changing it to
`$("#messform").submit(function() {`

I have a new problem, when the fancybox closes, it redirects the page its on, how can i stop this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to be clear you wish to only change the fancybox's content?

if that is the case then I suggest the following:

```
$("#messform").submit(function() {
                var emailval  = $("#contactEmail").val();
                var msgval    = $("#c_message").val();
                var msglen    = msgval.length;
                var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);


                var mailvalid = true;
                var msgval    = $("#c_message").val();
                var msglen    = msgval.length;


                if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
                    // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                    // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                    $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'sendmesse.php',
                        data: $("#messform").serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data == "true") {
                                $("#messform").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                                    $(this).before("<strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong>");
                                    // setTimeout($.fancybox.close(), 1000);
                                    // $('.fancybox').close();
                                    // $.fancybox.close();
                                    setTimeout(function(){ $.fancybox.close();}, 1000);

                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

// This part is important because you are using a ajax post so you would want to ignore the normal form submission.
                 return false;
             });
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#messform").submit(function() {
```

is calling form action, so use `return false;` inside. Don't know if this is issue, but give it a go :)